# UIButton imageEdgeInsets not updating at run time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, imageedgeinsets

So here is my code, it's fairly strait forward.

```
CGFloat spaceing = 5;

self.premiumButton.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(spaceing,spaceing,spaceing,spaceing)
 NSLog(@"immage - %@",    NSStringFromUIEdgeInsets(self.premiumButton.imageEdgeInsets));
```

right should update the Image to be in the center of the button with a 5 point padding on all sides(I've removed the text for this particular state)

but the log comes back with

> immage - {0, 0, 0, 0}

Infact I placed this in initWithCoder which is how this view is being built from a xib and got the same thing despite the fact that in the interface builder I set everything.

What am I missing everything else on stack overflow has code samples that look just like mine marked as the answer but it's not doing anything for me.

I have tried the UIButton setTitleEdgeInsets method but no go.

Comment: and what happens when you put this in "override func layoutSubviews() {"?

Comment: still gives me {0, 0, 0, 0}

Comment: k, sorry about that, looks like some double trouble then

Comment: Try to set it in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`. Clean project and run again

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)layoutSubviews update imageEdgeInsets
```